# Close panel in jquery/css in Office UI Fabric JS

Tags: office-ui-fabric

How do I close a panel in Office UI Fabric JS when click on button?

In Bootrap I have the options via CSS by adding

```
data-dismiss="modal" to the button class
```

Also in bootstrap I have the option in jquery to hide a modal by

```
$('#myModal').modal('hide');
```

What is the jquery equivalent for Office UI Fabric to hide an already opened panel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could trigger the existing Panel close button via jQuery

```
$(".ms-Panel-closeButton").trigger("click");
```